# Changing value of drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the value of a drop down that has select nested in DIV's. I tried using this jquery to change the default value to one of the options.

```js
function selectSearch() {
  $('select__select choices__input is-hidden option').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'DEFAULT DROP OPTION';
  }).attr('selected', false);
  $('select__select choices__input is-hidden option').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'OPTION ONE';
  }).attr('selected', true);
  $('.select__select choices__input is-hidden').change();
  $('.searcher__button').click();
  return $('select__select choices__input is-hidden').val()
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choices__inner">
  <select class="select__select choices__input is-hidden" id="select-257" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-choice="active">
    <option value="" selected="">DEFAULT DROP OPTION</option>
  </select>
  <div class="choices__list choices__list--single">
    <div class="choices__item choices__item--selectable" data-item="" data-id="3" data-value="" aria-selected="true">
      DEFAULT DROP OPTION
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="choices__list choices__list--dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><input type="text" class="choices__input choices__input--cloned" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Buscar..." aria-activedescendant="choices--select-257-item-choice-1">
  <div class="choices__list" dir="ltr" role="listbox">
    <div class="choices__group" data-group="" data-id="949837641428" data-value="" role="group">
      <div class="choices__heading"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable is-highlighted" data-select-text="Press to select" data-choice="" data-id="1" data-value="" data-choice-selectable="" id="choices--select-257-item-choice-1" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">
      DEFAULT OPTION
    </div>
    <div class="choices__group" data-group="" data-id="859859147502" data-value="Destacados" role="group">
      <div class="choices__heading">Destacados</div>
    </div>
    <div class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable" data-select-text="Press to select" data-choice="" data-id="2" data-value="7" data-choice-selectable="" id="choices--select-257-item-choice-2" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      OPTION ONE
    </div>
```

Comment: Which library are you using for the select elements?

Comment: This is for a webscrapper, I Inject javascript script into the webbrowser which uses Microsoft IE 11 javascript engine to run the scripts.

Comment: And... what's the problem?

Comment: I am not able to change the value from the default to one of the selects so the scrapper can gather data from that particular selection. For now I am using the url but I would like to find a solution because a lot more websites are switching to this type of drop down that do some sort of bubbling up the dom. 
Sidenote: When you click the selection it does an ajax call behind the scenes. In the paste I've edited the text using jquery and used change and then clicked the search button and it's worked but not anymore with this latest site change.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem comes from the wrong selectors, you need to join the classes using the dot `.` since they belong to the same element, like :

```
.select__select.choices__input.is-hidden
```

Whole code :

```
function selectSearch() {
  $('.select__select.choices__input.is-hidden option').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'DEFAULT DROP OPTION';
  }).attr('selected', false);

  $('.select__select.choices__input.is-hidden option').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'OPTIONONE';
  }).attr('selected', true);

  $('.select__select.choices__input.is-hidden').change();
  $('.searcher__button').click();

  return $('.select__select.choices__input.is-hidden').val();
};
```

Comment: My mistake, I grabbed the wrong jquery solution I had, I had the dot for class and it still does not work.

Comment: Please let me know Which library are you using for the select elements?

Comment: I am using a web scrapper, so what I am doing is injecting this script into the web browser which uses Microsoft IE 11 javascript engine.

Comment: The website is using the library **[Choices](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices)** IMO you can't simply select the value by adding `selected` attribute.

Comment: Any idea on how to change the value using a script?